# Completable Future not cancelled but Done

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following `Runnable`

```
task = () -> {
    while(true) {
        loopPreparation();

        _chunkRxTask = receiveChunk(); /*completable future */

        try {
            _chunkRxTask.get();
        }catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

I start it like this :

```
_asyncTask = CompletableFuture.runAsync(task);
```

And later on I'd like to finish it by

```
if ( _asyncTask != null ) {
    _asyncTask.cancel(true);
    _asyncTask = null;
}
```

I see that `_asyncTask.isDone() == true` but it's loop continues running. How to stop it properly? Do I always need to stop internal `_chunkRxTask`?

Comment: Your loop won't stop until you get an exception which is probably not what you want. Add an additional stop condition.

Comment: I expected that cancelling a future would terminate this loop. Am I wrong? Like when you call interrupt() for thread instance.

Comment: Well, your loop isn't checking for any "cancelled" condition and as far as I know the tasks are executed by a thread pool so you don't want to interrupt those threads. Thus the task itself would need to be "cancellable". This might help: http://blog.tremblay.pro/2017/08/supply-async.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. The correct solution in my case would be adding CancellationException in catch and cancel _chunkRxTask. But what I still do not understand is the fact that isDone returns true for _asyncTask but it's not done really. Is it a known feature?

Comment: Well, if you cancelled it is basically done (not successful though) so from a user's point of view there's no need to further wait for the future to complete.

Comment: So it seems that to guarantee that the internal loop is finished I have to call join(). I'll post the final solution right now. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The final solution for my issue looks as follows :

```
task = () -> {
    while(true) {
        loopPreparation();

        _chunkRxTask = receiveChunk(); /*completable future */

        try {
            _chunkRxTask.get();
        }catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | CancellationException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

And to stop this activity :

```
if ( _asyncTask != null ) {
    if ( _chunkRxTask != null ) {
        _chunkRxTask.cancel(true);
        _chunkRxTask = null;
    }

    _asyncTask.join();
    _asyncTask = null;
}
```